# String Pass by value

Tags: c++, string, function, turbo-c++

Turbo C++: I would like to pass a string to a function without changing original data(pass by value). How to achieve in this code???

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void pass(char g[20])
{
 g[0]=g[2];
 cout<<"\nPassed: ";
 for(int i=0;i<strlen(g);i++)
 cout<<g[i];
}
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 char a[20];
 cout<<"\nEnter the Data: ";
 cin.get(a,sizeof a);
 int len=strlen(a);
 pass(a);
 cout<<"\nAfter pass: ";
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
 cout<<a[i];
 getch();
}
```

Comment: Copy the string before you pass it.

Comment: First stop writing non standard C++ code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-to-use-turbo-c

Comment: Take a look at `strdup()` but know that you are responsible for freeing it before returning.

Comment: Turbo C++ is completely outdated. Stop using it and learn standard C++. In particular, Standard C++ makes this problem *trivial* to solve.

Comment: Is there lot of difference b/w Turbo c++ and standard c++. Because I'm going to be a programmer soon. If the difference is large then I need time to learn which is not possible in current situation. Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Strings in C are character arrays that have `'\0'` as the last element (with some syntactic sugar to define such arrays). Arrays in C are not first class citizens; particularly, they cannot be passed as arguments. When you pass an array into a function, the function will recieve a pointer to the first element of the array. The pointed to memory is not copied, only the pointer is. Because of that, when modifying the pointed to memory, the memory in the calling function is modified.

C++ inherited these characteristics from C. If you want to use C strings as you described, you have to copy them manually, either before passing them into the function, or within the function itself.

However, the preferred method in C++ is, to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) from the C++ standard library. In your case, it would be sufficient to declare `pass` as

```
void pass(std::string g)
```

and replace `strlen(g)` with `g.length()`.

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot use **string** because _turbo c++_ is old compiler and **string** is not valid there

Answer (score 0):

In C++ when you you pass a character array, base address of character array is passed.

It means automatically call by address is made.That's why changes made to formal arguments reflect back to actual argument.

You cannot pass a character array by value.

But alternatively , you can pass each character of a string by value and store each character in another variable in that function.

Or you can make a temporary variable in function to store the original string and then make changes with temporary string.

You can also use std:string class instead of a character array. In this case simply passing the variable will do the work (passing by value).

Comment: Au contraire. In C++, when you pass a string, you pass an object of class `std::string` or closely related. What you said is true for the case where you decide to pass a C string, of course, but the two should not be confused.